# Azure CDN Rewrite URL to index.html not working

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-cdn

I have a static website with one $web container and one more container named storybook containing a build in the $web container. Currently to reach the storybook container I have to write: www.xyz/storybook/index.hmtl.
The goal is to reach the Image when calling www.xyz/storybook.
To achieve this I tried to setup Rule Engines URL Rewrite.
[My rule looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTY2I.png)
Somehow the rewrite is not working and I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you give us more information on what's not working. Are you getting a 404? Or is it not redirecting?

Comment: The redirection is not working. Since www.xyz/storybook does not redirect, I get a 404.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment i am getting the same error as 404:***

Thus, to resolve this issue, check whether you have provided correct Html ***error document path*** as below:

[image]

In `$web` container, I have added my *error document path* as `abc.html` file and *my image files* as well. In document path, try to ***add your image URL path*** as below:

[image]

Also, when I try to browse my primary endpoint URL, I am ***getting the image successfully*** as shown below.  For this, make sure your container’s access level should be ***public container (anonymous read access for container and blobs)*** and I created ***azure CDN under security + networking.***

[image]

Check whether you have given correct origin path default as below:

[image]

To access the image, copy the **Endpoint hostname along with your image url path** as below that is, Append with blob url **`(/$web/abc.html)`** by omitting origin hostname`(https://imran955.blob.core.windows.net)`

i.e., `https://Endpointhostname/blob url`

[image]
[image]

***Result***:

[image]